# Get List of Contacts in a ListManager and associate one more contact to it

Tags: sitecore-api, list-manager

I have a requirement to get Contact data from a Registration page and save that data into a List Manager in Sitecore.

I followed the below approach.

```
//Create ListManager Object
var listManager = (ListManager)Factory.CreateObject("contactListManager", true);

//Find ListManager by Id so that later I can associate a contact to it.
var list = listManager.FindById("{5A144595-1EDD-4109-A271-25CB13E83503}");
```

But while finding the listmanager by id I am getting `Duplicate Ids Not allowed` error. (I am taking Id from Sitecore Item)

I searched in almost all sites for resolving this issue but could not find a solution. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a blog post describing what you need:

> [Sitecore - proper way of adding contacts to contact lists](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-add-contact-to-a-contact-list)
>   .

You should reference `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.dll` and use

```
Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ClientApi.UpdateSubscriptions
```

You need to fill `email`, `firstname` and `lastname` of your contact first.

So your code can look like this:

```
string managerRoot = ID_OF_THE_ITEM /sitecore/content/Email Campaign;
string contactList = "{697E3130-0BEF-4DD7-C8EB-C165D70D604A}";

if (!Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive)
    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.StartTracking();

var currentContact = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact;

var personal = currentContact.GetFacet<Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Entities.IContactPersonalInfo>("Personal");

personal.FirstName = SOME_FIRST_NAME;
personal.Surname = SOME_LAST_NAME;

var emailAddresses = currentContact.GetFacet<Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Entities.IContactEmailAddresses>("Emails");
if (!emailAddresses.Entries.Contains("Email"))
{
    emailAddresses.Entries.Create("Email");
}

var email = emailAddresses.Entries["Email"];
email.SmtpAddress = SOME_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
emailAddresses.Preferred = "Email";

var recipientId = new Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Xdb.XdbContactId(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ClientApi.UpdateSubscriptions(recipientId, new[] { contactList }, new string[] { }, managerRoot, false);
```

More information can be found here [The Email Experience Manager Client API](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/subscription_management/the_exm_client_api)

You should not use `contact.Tags.Set` and `contact.Tags.Remove` for adding contact to a contact list. This can cause problems with list locking and list recipients count not being updated correctly.

Comment: Hi Marek, 

Thank you for your suggestions. I followed the approach but when using UpdateSubscriptions it is giving the following error :

The item ID: {BC799B34-8423-48AC-A2FE-D128E6300659} could not find the Email Experience Manager Root it requested. 

The Item ID used is the List Root ID. Tried with List Manager Folder ID as well but got the same error. 

Appreciate any suggestions on that?

Comment: I assume you have EXM installed, correct? ManagerRootId should be the ID of the `/sitecore/content/Email Campaign` item

Comment: @Keshava Is this a single instance setup or a scaled setup? I.e. do you have a dedicated CD and CM server? If you do not, you do not need EXM to add a contact to a contact list.

Comment: Hi Marek,  Thank you very much for your support. It works now.
You rockk!

Comment: Marek, Thank you once again. Just had one more question. Can we add a single contact into multiple contact lists? I tried adding the same contact into 2 Lists by writing this code twice and changing the contact list ID : Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ClientApi.UpdateSubscriptions(recipientId, new[] { contactList }, new string[] { }, managerRoot, false);
But it was taking only the first one. Any suggestion on this? Or is it that we can link a single contact to only one Contact List?

Comment: You need to pass both contact list in the array, so like `UpdateSubscriptions‌​(recipientId, new[] { contactList1, contactList2 }, ...`

Comment: Thank you @MarekMusielak once again. The code works fine when I try to add 2 entries, but when I try to associate the Contact to some 24+ lists it just does not update all the 24 lists. I tried to have a loop and associate the Contact with each Lists with a gap of 1 sec inside the loop using Thread.Sleep(1000) . It is still missing to add the contacts to few lists. But when I debug the application the loop runs and it adds the contact to all the lists. Is there any other way to add the contact to 24+ lists? Sorry to trouble you again.

Comment: I have no idea. You need to contact Sitecore Support